# Callback to control modal display

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have built a modal to display login/register modal. By default, the modal is opened by another component using the props `show`. This working when the modal is called by this component.

Also the modal `Form` is called from my Header.js as shown below:

`<LoginRegisterForm displayPopUp={this.state.showLogin} onHide={() => this.setState({ showLogin: false })}/>}`

In this case, the state `showLogin` is set to true when clicking on the `Login/Register`, the `<LoginRegisterform` is now showing the modal because `displayPopup` props is set to `true`

The code is below:

Form.js

```
const Form = ({ initialState = STATE_SIGN_UP, displayPopUp}) => {
  const [mode, toggleMode] = useToggle(initialState);
  const [display, toggleDisplay] = useToggleDisplay(displayPopUp);

  console.log('----------------------------------------------------------')
  console.log('displayPopUp: ' + displayPopUp)
  console.log('display: ' + display)
  console.log('toggleDisplay: ' + toggleDisplay)
  console.log('----------------------------------------------------------')

 
  return (
    <Modal className="modal" show={displayPopUp}  size="lg">
        <Container pose={mode === STATE_LOG_IN ? "signup" : "login"}>
        <div className="container__form container__form--one">
            <FormLogin mode={mode} toggleDisplay={toggleDisplay} />
        </div>
        <div className="container__form container__form--two">
            <FormSignup mode={mode} toggleDisplay={toggleDisplay}/>
        </div>
        <Overlay toggleMode={toggleMode} mode={mode} />
        </Container>
    </Modal>
  );
};
```

in the `FormLogin`, I do have a `Cancel` button which allow me to close the modal located in the `Form.js` when needed. However, I do not know how I can make the modal close by change the `show` params in the `Form.js` when the close control is in the class `FormLogin`

FormLogin.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'

import SocialButton from './styled/SocialButton'
import SlidingForm from './styled/SlidingForm'

import WhiteButton from '../../materialdesign/WhiteButton'

import { faFacebook, faGoogle, faLinkedinIn } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons'

import Auth from '../../../data/network/Auth';
import Constant from '../../../config/Constant';

import CancelIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Cancel';


class FormLogin extends React.Component {

    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          email: '',
          password: '',
          loading: false,
          error: '',
          toggleDisplay: this.props.toggleDisplay
        };
    }

    requestSignIn = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
  
        this.setState({loading: true})
  
        try {
          const authData = await Auth.getToken(`${this.state.email}`, `${this.state.password}`);
          sessionStorage.setItem(Constant.ALL, authData)
          sessionStorage.setItem(Constant.AUTH_TOKEN, authData.token)
          sessionStorage.setItem(Constant.DISPLAY_NAME, authData.user_display_name)
          sessionStorage.setItem(Constant.EMAIL, authData.user_email)
          sessionStorage.setItem(Constant.NICENAME, authData.user_nicename)
  
          window.open("/", "_self") //to open new page
          this.setState({loading: false })
          this.close()
        } catch (error) {
          console.warn("Connection to WP - Auth Token failed ")
          console.error(error);
        } 
      }

    requestForgotPassword = () => {
    }

    handleOnChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value})
    }

    render(){

        const { email, password } = this.state;
        
        return(
            <SlidingForm>  
                 <div style={{textAlign:"left"}}>
                    <CancelIcon style={{ color: "#ff7255" }} onClick={() => this.state.toggleDisplay(false) }/>
                </div>         
                <h1 style={titleStyle}>Sign in</h1>
                <div style={{textAlign: "center"}}>
                <SocialButton>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faFacebook} />
                </SocialButton>
                <SocialButton>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faGoogle} />
                </SocialButton>
                <SocialButton>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faLinkedinIn} />
                </SocialButton>
                </div>
                <p style={txtStyle}>or use your account</p>
                <form style={{textAlign: "center"}}>
                <input style={formStyle} placeholder="Email" type="text" name="email" value={ email } onChange={ this.handleOnChange }/>
                <input style={formStyle} placeholder="Password" type="password" name="password" value={ password } onChange={ this.handleOnChange } />
                </form>
                <p style={txtSpan}>
                <a href="#" onClick={this.requestForgotPassword}>Forgot your password?</a>
                </p>
                <div style={{textAlign: "center", marginTop: "15px"}}>
                    <WhiteButton text="Sign in" onClick={this.requestSignIn}></WhiteButton>
                </div>
            </SlidingForm>
        );
    }
}

export default FormLogin
```

For now I was doing this :

`<CancelIcon style={{ color: "#ff7255" }} onClick={() => this.state.toggleDisplay(false)`

but it's not working, it's seems not having control on the `Form.js`.

toggleDisplay code is below:

```
import { useState } from 'react'

export const STATE_SHOW = true
export const STATE_HIDE = false

const useToggleDisplay = initialDisplayState => {
  const [display, setDisplay] = useState(initialDisplayState)
  const toggleDisplay = () =>
    setDisplay(display === false ? true : false)
    console.log('-%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%')
    console.log('display: ' + display)
    console.log('toggleDisplay: ' + toggleDisplay)
    console.log('-%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%')
  return [display, toggleDisplay]
}

export default useToggleDisplay
```

The Overall logic:

- Modal is called from `Header.js` and show is set to false by default and switch to true when clicking on the menu option login
- The Modal Form.js is handling login and register screen

What is the best option to be able to set `show` to `false` in the `Form.js` when the close is triggered in the `FormLogin.js` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assigning the `toggleDisplay` prop to local `state`, just invoke the `prop` directly. This should work for updating the `<Form />`'s `display` state to `false`.

Also, do you intend for the `<CancelIcon />` to toggle the `modal` open/close state, or is it just to close the modal? If it's the latter, you may want to update the `prop` name to `closeModal` instead of `toggleDisplay`.

```
<div style={{textAlign:"left"}}>
  <CancelIcon style={{ color: "#ff7255" }} onClick={() => this.props.toggleDisplay(false) 
  }/>
</div>
```

Your `useToggleDisplay` func is confusing, and the original version was not accepting any arguments for `toggleDisplay`, hence even though you passed in `false`, it did not update the `display` state. I've removed `useToggleDisplay` since it doesn't do anything special.

```
const [display, setDisplay] = useState(initialDisplayState)
```

I also realised that `<Modal />` is accepting `displayPopUp` instead of `display`. If you use `displayPopUp`, it doesn't know that `display` has been set to `false`, and therefore, remain open. And I passed `setDisplay` setter to the `<FormLogin />` components.

```
<Modal className="modal" show={display}  size="lg">
  <Container pose={mode === STATE_LOG_IN ? "signup" : "login"}>
    <div className="container__form container__form--one">
      <FormLogin mode={mode} toggleDisplay={setDisplay} />
     </div>
     <div className="container__form container__form--two">
       <FormSignup mode={mode} toggleDisplay={setDisplay}/>
      </div>
      <Overlay toggleMode={toggleMode} mode={mode} />
   </Container>
 </Modal>
```

Comment: it's not working. I have added the code for th toggleDisplay for help

Comment: Thanks still not working but perhaps it comes from the `<Modal>` in the `Form.js` the `show` is controled by the default value sent by my header class as initial value

Comment: I think `<Modal />` is accepting the wrong `state`. It should be accepting `display`.

Comment: it seems that the `useState` is not working. when doing ` const [display, toggleDisplay] = useToggleDisplay(displayPopUp);` when `displayPopUp` is set to `true`, `display` remain `false`

Comment: I've cleaned up the code and updated it. Please take a look again.

Comment: thanks. I think maybe the way I am displaying the modal or `showing` is is not correct